# Javascript: Remove an item and return the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to remove an item from array and only remove one even if there are more than two same item.
For example:

```
let array = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "def"];
const toRemove = "def";
```

I tried finding index and splice it but it returns deleted array.

```
const index = array.indexOf(toRemove);
console.log(array.splice(index,1)); //["def"]
```

What I need is instead of that, how can I can get remaining array variable `["abc", "ghi", "def"]`?

Comment: splice modifies the original array and returns the deleted element, just log array itself after calling splice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there.
**splice()** will modify the original array and return an array with the modified value(s). You need to pass not only the `start`, but also a `deleteCount` argument.
After that, you only need to access your original array:

```js
let array = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "def"];
const toRemove = "def";
const removed = array.splice(array.indexOf(toRemove), 1) // Passing deleteCount as 1 will remove only element
console.log(removed)
console.log(array);
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 1):

The splice() method adds/removes items to/from an array, and returns the removed item(s).

This method changes the original array.

```js
let array = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "def"];
const toRemove = "def";


const index = array.indexOf(toRemove);
if (index > -1) {
  console.log(array.splice(index, 1));
  console.log(array)
}
```